# WMD - get markdown text

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, wmd, wmd-editor

I'm using [markdown editor](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/) in my app.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var converter = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();
    var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter);
    editor.run();
});

<div class="wmd-panel">
    <div id="wmd-button-bar"></div>
    <textarea class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>        
</div>
<div id="wmd-preview" class="wmd-panel wmd-preview" name="Content"></div>
```

Initially, the textarea field is empty. After I enter some text, everything works as expected:

[image]

Firebug shows such html structure:

[image]

Now I need to get entered pure markdown text: `**where** is it ?`. I need it because I think it should be stored in the database (and later retrieved from database and converted to html when showed to the user). I have no idea how can it be reached. How can I get it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've have some [Docs](http://code.google.com/p/pagedown/wiki/PageDown) which might be helpful to you.

The fancy way would probably be to catch the `preConversion` event in the event-chain:

```
converter.hooks.chain('preConversion', function(markdown) {
  // Do something wonderful with you markdown variable, and then return it.
  return markdown;
});
```

The less fancy way, but working as expected would be to just retrieve the value of the value parameter of the textarea.

```
var textarea = document.getElemetById('wmd-input');
var markdown = textarea.value;
```